# How do I set some of an object's coordinates without resetting the other ones?

Tags: javascript, 3d, aframe, webvr

I am trying to adjust only the Y coordinate of an object, while keeping the X and Z coordinates the same. The only method that I have working is fetching the object's position and composing a new partially modified position. It's not pretty, and seems like it could be inefficient. It looks like this may be due to the fact that [position is a single-property component](https://aframe.io/docs/master/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute), so maybe this isn't possible.

Here's my current solution:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-position-example

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-camera id="camera"></a-camera>
    </a-scene>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
const camera = document.querySelector( '#camera' )

console.log( camera.getAttribute( 'position' ) )
// {x: 0, y: 1.6, z: 0}

// overwrites original position, as expected
camera.setAttribute( 'position', { x: 0, y: 0, z: 5 } )
console.log( camera.getAttribute( 'position' ) )
// {x: 0, y: 0, z: 5}

// overwrites original position (including z, defaults to 0), maybe not expected
camera.setAttribute( 'position', { x: 5, y: 5 } )
console.log( camera.getAttribute( 'position' ) )
// {x: 5, y: 5, z: 0}

// overwrites original position (x and z become 0), maybe not expected
camera.setAttribute( 'position', 'y', 10 )
console.log( camera.getAttribute( 'position' ) )
// {x: 0, y: 10, z: 0}

// how to change some position variables and keep the other ones the same
let oldPos = camera.getAttribute('position')
let newPos = { x: 4, y: oldPos.y, z: oldPos.z }
camera.setAttribute( 'position', newPos )
console.log( camera.getAttribute( 'position' ) )
// {x: 4, y: 10, z: 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

- Set a temporary `position` variable, and change only the desired part:
   `let pos = this.el.getAttribute('position');
    pos.x += velocity;
    this.el.setAttribute('position',pos);`
- use Rainer Witmann's idea of cutting the temporaries by using `Object.Assign()`:
  `this.el.setAttribute('position', Object.assign({}, this.el.getAttribute('position'), {x: newX}));`

  Seems shorter, but I like having the whole position as a temporary variable:
  live here: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/dqyszzz5/4/
- Mess with the `position` component directly, by changing data, and calling the `update()` function:
  `this.el.components.position.data.z-=2;
  this.el.components.position.update();`

  This is fun, but I think this is a terrible idea when creating a commercial/proffesional project, as every framework ingeration would be.
- use the threejs object3D properties:
  `this.el.object3D.position.x += velocity;`
  check it out in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/dqyszzz5/1/

   Please note, that later on You won't be able to call `getAttribute()`, as the position component does not change.

In Your glitch You use the first option, but You don't need use the position object attributes separately: `setAttribute('position',{x:pos.x,y:pos.y,z:pos.Z});`, You can simply use the whole object: `setAttribute('position',pos);`

Comment: Won't changing the underlying Three.js position mess things up later on? If I do `getAttribute('position')` on the box, won't it be the old position?  

And the second solution is what I'm currently doing, which looks like it may be the only way.

Comment: @jbjw yup, as i wrote, i usually use the 'temporary variable' option to keep things in place, I've updated my anwser to avoid confusion, if You're looking for a clean one liner, use Rainers idea, I still would like to have the position object as a whole in a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Something like this:

```
camera.setAttribute('position', Object.assign({}, camera.getAttribute('position'), {x: 5})
```

Comment: This still overwrites the whole position, but it looks like that's the only way and `Object.assign` is a lot prettier than my decompose-recompose solution. Thanks!